# Login Form Prominent - Sign up not prominent

Tags: login, registration, position

I've never understood why some sites make it very easy to log in, but hide the "register" link from your focus ( or vice versa ).

Tumblr, for example:  It's in the bottom left hand corner of the screen, and opaque as well.
[image]

What's the rationale?  Why isn't it below the login button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is: you've already registered.

Here's what I see:

[image]